# How to? - Apache Camel with Spring Boot and XML configuration

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have an application in which I am using Spring boot MVC and camel.
below is the code that I am running.

```
@ComponentScan({"com.xyz.routes","com.xyz.web","com.xyz.security"})
@SpringBootApplication
//@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/camelContext.xml")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        ApplicationContext applicationContext  = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

If I use @ImportResource annotation above (currently commented) the camel routes don't start.

For example below is without annotation.

```
INFO | 27 Apr 2018 15:26:31,149 | [main] org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started. |  |  | (DefaultCamelContext.java:2834)
INFO | 27 Apr 2018 15:26:31,150 | [main] org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.17.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.255 seconds |  |  | (DefaultCamelContext.java:2835)
```

And below two log lines are after I enabled annotation.

```
INFO | 27 Apr 2018 15:30:56,755 | [main] org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Total 0 routes, of which 0 are started. |  |  | (DefaultCamelContext.java:2834)
INFO | 27 Apr 2018 15:30:56,755 | [main] org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.17.0 (CamelContext: mtmSender) started in 0.089 seconds |  |  | (DefaultCamelContext.java:2835)
```

Any idea why this is not working when I enable the annotation? Note - Total routes are zero.

Please note that I need XML config because I am planning to define beans and properties there later.

Below is the camelContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
         ">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>${application-default.properties}</value>
                <value>${application.properties}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_NEVER" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sampleBean" class="com.xyz.model.SampleBean" />

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"  id="mtmSender">
        <properties>
            <property key="CamelLogDebugStreams" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

Comment: Could you try to add `<package>com.xyz.routes</package>` into `<camelContext>` section of camelContext.xml?

Comment: I am assuming you meant <packageScan><package>com.xyz.routes</package></packageScan>  correct? I tried that but didn't help. for the sake of trying, I also tried <package>com.xyz.routes</package> alone but that didn't work either.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it with your code and works for me. Is there any error in log? This is my working sample https://github.com/bedlaj/SpringBootCamelExample

Comment: Thanks for your example. I noticed that you have your route in xml and not in DSL. I also try putting my route definition in xml and that works. but the one in DSL does not work. looks like component scan is not picking it up. in my route, i have @Component annotation in front of class and i am extending FatJarRouter class.

Comment: In my example there are two routes. One with id `routeInDsl` in `MySpringBootRouter` and second with id `routeInXml` in `camelContext.xml`. Both routes started when added `@ImportResource`. Try extending regular `RouteBuilder`, I have never used `FatJarRouter` so cannot tell if it can cause some problems. Also `FatJarRouter` seems to be removed in actual Apache Camel.

Comment: Thanks! your example helped me. I was using spring boot version 2.0.1 (as parent) and deriving all the jars using that. Also I was implementing FatJarRouter. Once I changed my spring boot version to 1.5.10.RELEASE and also imported camel using the way you imported. using <!-- Camel BOM -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>  it worked fine.

Comment: Can you post your comment/solution as answer so I can accept? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After discussion with OP we have found, the problem was mixing Apache Camel dependencies with Spring Boot 2.0.x dependencies.

Because of some breaking API changes in Spring Boot 2.0.x, Apache Camel does not support Spring Boot 2.0 yet.

This is also mentioned in [Apache Camel 2.21.0 release notes](http://camel.apache.org/camel-2210-release.html)

> This release supports only Spring Boot 1.5.x. Support for Spring Boot 2.0.x is coming in Camel version 2.22 which is planned for early summer 2018.

For now the solution is to use Spring Boot 1.5.x with Apache Camel.

**POM with actual compatible dependencies:**

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot BOM -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.12.RELEASE</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Camel BOM -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>2.21.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

  <!-- Spring Boot -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Camel -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-stream-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Test -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.12.RELEASE</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```